# Thunderbird doesn't recognize email file format - attaches instead of opening a file

Tags: email, thunderbird, mail

Is there a way to force thunderbird to open a file as an email instead of attaching it in a new email form? `mbsync` by default downloads files without extension, which confuses thunderbird (and some other programs), but when copied and appended with `.eml` thunderbird opens them just fine.

Is there any workaround to solve it? Can linux somehow alias a file with a different name when opening it?

Comment: No, when you want to open a file, you have to use it's name. Either rename the file or create a link where the link has the `.eml` extension

Comment: `T-bird 102, Menu:File > Open > Saved Message > ...` ?

Comment: Thanks, @Hannu I confirm that your method works, but ideally you could do the same from the terminal.

Comment: @mook765 thanks, that makes sense although it complicates some scripts, because you need to clean all the links/copies afterwards.

Comment: Maybe there is some trick with bash file redirection that could temporarily map the file to memory, rename it and present to thunderbird without writing anything new to the disk?

Comment: Try renaming the file w .eml extension, then do `xdg-open filename`, might work.  (I believe it is pre-installed, if not, then `apt install xdg-utils`)

Comment: Hmm, renaming the file may break other programs that would expect it to still be there. The idea of adding a quick symbolic link to it and opening it instead would work fine if it wasn't for the mess on disk it could potentially create if something anything wrong. I'm looking currently for symbolic links that would be removed automatically after the process exits. Putting them in /tmp or some tempoorary directory isn't great neither, because this can also create a bit of a mess.

Comment: ... create them in /tmp ?

Comment: @Hannu haha thanks, I've just mentioned that in the last comment :)

Comment: Uh... didn't read all as it seems. ;-p - well.

Comment: I forgot about "process substitution": running `cat <(SELECTED-FILE-NAME)` makes `SELECTED-FILE-NAME` look like a `/proc/self/fd/14` for the process - the trick now would be to find a way to rename `14` to `14.eml`